# How to adjust today extension width for iOS 9 iPad Notification in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

So in iOS 9 for iPad the landscape mode splits the notification center into 2 unequal halves. Before, my today extension would fit perfectly in the notification center whether it was landscape or portait mode.

Does anyone know how to resize/scale my today extension to for the new iOS9 landscape notification center?  Also is there any particular way to find out if the widget/today extension will be on the left hand side or right hand side of the notification center? (since they are different widths)

[image: here is a screenshot displaying the 2 different sized halves.]

I have looked into, using autoResizing and autoResizeSubviews. But that doesnt seem to be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by obtaining my widget extension width with:

```
self.view.bounds.size.width
```

Attention, you have to access self.view in ***viewDidAppear*** because on *viewDidLoad* it may be incorrect, as reported here: [Getting width of the Notification-Center inside Today-Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085840/getting-width-of-the-notification-center-inside-today-extension/29320687?noredirect=1#comment52503586_29320687)

Actually, as I know, there is no API to know if your widget is on the left or on the right side of the notification center. But, for example, you can determine it by checking the ratio (*screensize / widget-size*), or you can calculate your layout in a relative manner, based on the width of your widget, as I do and I recommend.

Just for a numeric example, on the iPad mini 1 with iOS 9, the screen size in landscape is 1024*768, the widget width on the left side is 471 points and on the right side is 328 points.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you @Raiden996.